# Input() IF ELSE Control statement in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, if-statement, input

I have a dataset where, whenever a date value is input, specific date columns will shift.

**Data**

```
location    type    mig1        de          mig2        re
ny          aa      8/1/2021    10/1/2021   1/1/2022    2/1/2022
ny          aa      8/1/2021    10/1/2021   1/1/2022    2/1/2022
ca          aa      8/1/2021    10/1/2021   1/1/2022    2/1/2022
tx          bb      9/1/2021    11/1/2021   2/1/2022    3/1/2022
```

**Desired**

```
 #Date 8/1/2022 is input, which yields:

    location    type    mig1        de          mig2        re
    ny          aa      03/1/2022   05/1/2022   8/1/2022    7/1/2022
    ny          aa      03/1/2022   05/1/2022   8/1/2022    7/1/2022
    ca          aa      03/1/2022   05/1/2022   8/1/2022    7/1/2022
    tx          bb      03/1/2021   11/1/2021   08/1/2022   3/1/2022
```

Input prompt will ask user which date value they wish to input.
**User inputs the date '8/1/2021'**, **which updates the remaining column date values.** based on rules above.

**Doing**

```
datevalue = pd.to_datetime(input("Enter shift: "))


 if(df[type] == 'aa'):

         d = {
             'mig1': pd.DateOffset(months=5),
             'de': pd.DateOffset(months=3),
             're': pd.DateOffset(months=1),
             }
         s = pd.Series(d).rsub(datevalue)
         df.assign(**{**s, 'mig2': datevalue})
 else:
         e = {
             'mig1': pd.DateOffset(months=5),
        
             }
         s1 = pd.Series(e).rsub(datevalue)
         df.assign(**{**s1, 'mig2': datevalue})
```

**Logic:**

Date value in the `mig2` column is entered into the input() prompt, **mig1, de** and **re** values shift according to these rules:

```
   mig1 is 5 months from the date entered in the input() prompt
   de   is 3 months from the date entered in the input() prompt
   re   is 1 month from the date entered in the input() prompt
   Where [type] column values == 'aa'
```

**The only data that is changing are the **dates**, which are essentially getting shifted based upon the user input.**

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
input = datetime(2022, 8, 1)
conditions = {'mig1':5, 'de':3, 're':1}
def apply_this(x):
    if x.name == 'mig2':
        return [input]*len(x)
    else:
        return [input - pd.DateOffset(months=conditions[x.name])]*len(x)

date_cols =['mig1', 'de', 're', 'mig2']
df.loc[df['type'] == 'aa', date_cols] = df[date_cols].apply(lambda x: apply_this(x))

print(df)
```

`OUTPUT`

```
  location type       mig1         de       mig2         re
0       ny   aa 2022-03-01 2022-05-01 2022-08-01 2022-07-01
1       ny   aa 2022-03-01 2022-05-01 2022-08-01 2022-07-01
2       ca   aa 2022-03-01 2022-05-01 2022-08-01 2022-07-01
3       tx   bb 2021-09-01 2021-11-01 2022-02-01 2022-03-01
```

`SETUP`

```
data = {'location': ['ny', 'ny', 'ca', 'tx'], 
        'type': ['aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'bb'], 
        'mig1': ['2021-08-01 00:00:00', '2021-08-01 00:00:00', '2021-08-01 00:00:00', '2021-09-01 00:00:00'],
        'de': ['2021-10-01 00:00:00', '2021-10-01 00:00:00', '2021-10-01 00:00:00', '2021-11-01 00:00:00'],
        'mig2': ['2022-01-01 00:00:00', '2022-01-01 00:00:00', '2022-01-01 00:00:00', '2022-02-01 00:00:00'],
        're': ['2022-02-01 00:00:00', '2022-02-01 00:00:00', '2022-02-01 00:00:00', '2022-03-01 00:00:00']}


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
for col in ['mig1', 'de', 'mig2', 're']:
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col])
```

**EDIT according to discussion in comments:**

```
conditions = {'de':3, 're':1}
def apply_this(x):
    return [input - pd.DateOffset(months=conditions[x.name])]*len(x)

date_cols =['de', 're']
df.loc[df['type'] == 'aa', date_cols] = df[date_cols].apply(lambda x: apply_this(x))
df['mig1'] = input - pd.DateOffset(months=5)
df['mig2'] = input
```

Comment: ok thank you- I am wondering can I store time in input()? datevalue = pd.to_datetime(input("Enter date: "))

Comment: are you showing the date being entered 8/1/2022 as an input prompt? thank you

Comment: Yes you can replace the first line in my code with: `input = pd.to_datetime(input("Enter shift: "))`

Comment: ok thank you - I keep getting: TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not callable - is it due to var name?

Comment: On which line you are getting this error?

Comment: this line: input = pd.to_datetime(input("Enter shift: "))

Comment: its strange, its working fine for me

Comment: ok I see it is working but the rows w 'aa' have numbers and not dates: 1596240000000000000    - also it is not in dataframe format -

Comment: Are the date columns in original dataframe in datetime format?

Comment: I will need to convert to datetime. Thank you

Comment: I have added the setup, you can check that

Comment: ok thank you I appreciate it- I will test

Comment: when I check df.info() these columns should reflect datetime right? after performing pd.to.datetime?

Comment: Yes `datetime64[ns]` specifically

Comment: oh @muhammad - I see actually not getting desired. IF == bb , or not 'aa', de and re columns are not supposed to change- (refer to Desired output) I am researching

Comment: "IF == bb , de and re columns are not supposed to change", they should not change and this makes sure that `df.loc[df['type'] == 'aa', date_cols]`

Comment: ok thank you yes, but I am wanting the remaining columns to change like the others 'aa'  - so mig1 and mig2 should still be changing (based on desired output in post)

Comment: So here is what you want: `de` and `re` should change according to the input, but for only those rows where `type == aa`. Whereas `mig2` should be replaced with `input` for all the rows and lastly `mig1` should be shifted according to input for all rows as well. is this right?

Comment: Yes that is correct, all rows should change (according to input) when type == aa , but when type = 'bb' only mig1 and mig2 values will change (according to input) @Muhammad

Comment: Ok thank you will apply this -

Comment: Could you explain what this is doing : [x.name])]*len(x) I will research but I think you are taking the parameter x and then multiplying by this parameter? @Muhammad

Comment: `x` is a series, you can print `x` inside function and you will get to know what its doing. use these statements inside function, `print(x.name), print(type(x)), print(x.name)`

Comment: Ok I will and why multiply by Len with this? [input]*len(x) @Muhammad

Comment: because we want the returned array to be equal to the no of rows where condition `(i.e. type == aa)` matched

Comment: Ah yes ok I am trying to learn from the output so can build from this_ many thanks for the response

Comment: is it possible to change input to an integer vs date like my recent post? @muhammad